# problema em deixar uma texto na esquerda e 2 itens na direita

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.col-item {
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #000;
}
.col-item .photo img
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.col-item .info
{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.col-item:hover .info {
    background-color: #F5F5DC;
}
.col-item .price
{
    /*width: 50%;*/
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.col-item .price h5
{
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.price-text-color
{
    color: #219FD1;
}


.col-item .separator
{
    border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
}

.clear-left
{
    clear: left;
}
.col-item .btn-add
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}


.col-item .btn-details
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.controls
{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
[data-slide="prev"]
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-right mt-3 mb-3">
      <h3 class="mr-0">Novidades</h3>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary prev" href="" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary next" href="" title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu te aconselharia a usar os elementos separados dentro do Grid...

Dessa foram, uma `col` para o `H3` e uma `col` para os Btns

```css
    
  .col-item {
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #000;
}
.col-item .photo img
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.col-item .info
{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.col-item:hover .info {
    background-color: #F5F5DC;
}
.col-item .price
{
    /*width: 50%;*/
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.col-item .price h5
{
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.price-text-color
{
    color: #219FD1;
}


.col-item .separator
{
    border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
}

.clear-left
{
    clear: left;
}
.col-item .btn-add
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}


.col-item .btn-details
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.controls
{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
[data-slide="prev"]
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
      <div class="col-3"><h3 class="mr-0">Novidades</h3></div>
        <div class="col-9 text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary prev" href="" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary next" href="" title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## OBS:

Se vc quiser colocar tudo em uma linha só, sem separa os elementos em cols vc pode apenas colocar seu HTML assim, nem precisa de fazer CSS. Use as classes nativas `d-flex` junto da `col-12` para ela ficar com `display:flex` e `mr-auto` no `H3` para ele "colar" na esquerda

```
<div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex">
      <h3 class="mr-auto">Novidades</h3>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary prev" href="" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary next" href="" title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opa Hugão, cara como os botões vão para esquerda sem classe para eles?

Comment: @LeAndrade pq o mr-auto "empurra" eles  pra lá :) na verdade nem precisa do text-right na col-12. Isso é uma propriedade de comportamente normal do Flexbox

Comment: A jóia man, então é o mr-auto que faz a mágica aí. Valeu Hugo!!

Comment: @LeAndrade tipo assim. Com o d-flex na col ela vira um container flexbox, assim os filhos dela ficam em linha um depois do outro. o H3 que é o primeiro filho tem uma margem a direita automática, mr-auto, essa margem "empurra" o restante do conteúdo para direita até o final do container :), a mágica mesmo é o flexbox rss

Comment: Ahh sim entendi Hugo, obrigado!

Comment: @hugocsl https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333823/problema-com-uma-section-e-grid-no-bootstrap vc poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 3):

Uma das maneiras de se resolver isto é adicionando a classe do próprio Bootstrap `float-left` e `float-right`:

```css
.col-item {
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #000;
}
.col-item .photo img
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.col-item .info
{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.col-item:hover .info {
    background-color: #F5F5DC;
}
.col-item .price
{
    /*width: 50%;*/
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.col-item .price h5
{
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.price-text-color
{
    color: #219FD1;
}


.col-item .separator
{
    border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
}

.clear-left
{
    clear: left;
}
.col-item .btn-add
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}


.col-item .btn-details
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.controls
{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
[data-slide="prev"]
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
      <h3 class="mr-0 float-left">Novidades</h3>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary prev float-right" href="#" title="go back">>><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary next float-right" href="#" title="more"><<<i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"> </i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @leo opa man depois q eu fiz isso os >><< prev e next ficaram bugados tem como dar um help?

Comment: Eu coloquei isso só para exemplo aqui, pode tirar se quiser.

Comment: ahh verdd eu não tinha visto que vc tinha colocado os >> e << kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk, mds.. Vlw man!

Comment: Deixei apenas uma maneira utilizando a classe, mas, o mais indicado é como a resposta do Hugo mesmo!

Comment: @LeAndrade valeu jovem tmj. Se te interessar deixei uma OBS: na minha resposta que explico como usar as classes nativas para fazer isso, mantendo tudo em um Col- só, mas sem precisar criar CSS nem nada.